# Limits of a decentralised app due to racketeering by miners?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm learning about blockchain (finally). I like the idea of a decentralised app, especially for things like a decentralised twitter clone where users may with micropayments to use the app so that there aren't incentives for the centralised system to sow discord to generate more clicks.

The operating cost for a system like that would mostly be in paying the miners to process transactions (e.g messages or tweets) would be paid by users. But miners could also be users, and there's potential for those users to generate spam messages to drive up the amount of mining required.

I'm pretty sure my concerns are due to a lack of knowledge of blockchain, so can someone please help me understand how decentralised apps are designed to both public but also not susceptible to racketeering by those who get paid to process transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about public blockchains, then the technical protocols of the blockchain allow individual miners or a group of conspiracy miners, for example, not to process transactions from certain addresses, so that they always remain pending. The only protection against this is the presence of a large number of nodes in the network, which excludes the exclusive capture by "bad nodes" of the block generation process.